# Why was my site not aproved for AdSense?

Tags: google-search-console, google-adsense

Our new site http://www.sulabhloan.com has failed to get approval for AdSense.
Even though site look reasonably better we cant figure out what is the real issue for disapproval can somebody help regarding this?

EMAIL WE GOT :

> We did not approve your application for the reasons listed below.
>
> ### Issues:
>
> Site does not comply with Google policies

Further detail:

> Site does not comply with Google policies: We're unable to approve your
>   AdSense application at this time because we feel that your site does not
>   comply with Google AdSense policies or webmaster quality guidelines. It's
>   our goal to provide our advertisers sites that offer rich and meaningful
>   content, receive organic traffic, and allow us to serve well-targeted ads
>   to users. We believe that currently your site does not fulfill this
>   criteria.

Please help us find out the real factor which caused disapproval.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because you are using other people's content? For example, a [paragraph from your page](https://www.google.ee/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=A+personal+loan+is+a+loan+of+funds+made+by+a+bank+for+personal+use.+It+isn%27t+a+business+loan+or+a+home+loan+and+is+ideal+for+buying+a+car+or+furniture,+taking+a+holiday+or+consolidating+other+debts.#hl=et&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22A+personal+loan+is+a+loan+of+funds+made+by+a+bank+for+personal+use.+It+isn%27t+a+business+loan+or+a+home+loan+and+is+ideal+for+buying+a+car+or+furniture,+taking+a+holiday+or+consolidating+other+debts%22&oq=%22A+personal+loan+is+a+loan+of+funds+made+by+a+bank+for+personal+use.+It+isn%27t+a+business+loan+or+a+home+loan+and+is+ideal+for+buying+a+car+or+furniture,+taking+a+holiday+or+consolidating+other+debts%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...4203.4203.1.4668.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.1.1NJLHW59k5g&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1f12b28324050b95&biw=1304&bih=683).

Clearly not unique. And by looking the site, it doesn't add any value to users and it's reasonable Google to block it. If I would be an advertiser I wouldn't want my ads appear on your site.

Comment: Don't post shortened URLs. I can see why you likely did it, but the answer field doesn't restrict your length, so no point.

Comment: Additionally, there's very little content on the site in general, and what little content there is is of very low quality (random capitalization, bad formatting, misspellings, poor grammar, etc.). The few links which look like they might lead to useful content don't actually go anywhere.